# Conversion from shapefile to geodatabase feature class in ARCGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, esri-geodatabase, feature-class, domains

I have converted feature class from a geodatabase to shapefile, and after that I have updated some polygons in shapefile. Now I want to get back to the same feature class or a fress/new feature class in the same geodatabase.

How Can I perform this task in ArcGIS ?

**The Problem is**: I have a defined domains(codded-value-domain) in geodatabase (a dropdown will come for updation of attributes while editing(dropdown contains different land use class names and their codes)), but after converting from feature class to shapefile,in attribute table I only got codes for the landuse classes. After that I have updated some polygons in shapefile with same codes.

How can I get back to the same geodatabase as a feature class which has same domains using either its direct method or some script in ArcPy?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a new feature class in your database:

- import shapefile into database
- in ArcCatalog right click on feature class -> properties -> fields tab -> click on field and in field properties table below click on domain row and select appropriate domain (same as your original feature class)

If you want to bring your updates to original feature class you have to consider it thoughtfully. Basically if you just created new features, you can select only them and then use APPEND as Farid Cher advised. But if you did updates to existing polygons it could be tricky since you will need firstly delete those polygons from original feature class and then APPEND new ones. In this case I would advice delete all polygons in original feature class with *delete features* tool and then in ArcCatalog right click on feature -> load -> load data and load your shapefile with wizard. NOTE than with this approach your OBJECTID field values in original feature class will be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Truncate your feature class in the geodatabase (which has the domain) and use the APPEND tool to append features from your shapefile.

Answer (score -2):

First you create geodatabase (personal geodatabase or file geodatabase)

Then you use import tool to import shapefile to geodatabase

Tutorial for you here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b6-HjKT84Dc

Comment: This is extremely close to a link-only answer, which are [not encouraged](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer): `Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there`.  This is particularly true with a "late answer" (13 + months after the question)

Comment: The video is not even available anymore. This is why a description is so important.